# Does StackDriver support Syslog protocol?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, apigee, stackdriver

Does StackDriver support Syslog protocol? if so, can someone share an example?

For context, I'm looking to write logging entries to StackDriver using Syslog protocol. I've looked through the documentation and haven't a way to do so. So, far the closes approach seems to be using StackDriver agent. However, I want to leverage API Gateways such as Apigee, which support Syslog protocol through [Message Logging Policy](http://docs.apigee.com/api-services/reference/message-logging-policy).

I know that REST API could be leveraged to send these entries. However, I'm trying to avoid creating additional HTTP layers.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not supported. Confirmed by the team. I have ended up implementing a Node.js wrapper of the REST API using service account credentials for OAuth. I will publish the package in NPM for anyone who wants to leverage same.

Comment: this answer could do with an edit that adds some specifics that would allow others to replicate the solution. as it stands, there's not much useable information here.