# Can Stackdriver Logging receive syslog protocol?

Tags: logging, heroku, syslog, stackdriver, google-cloud-logging

Does Stackdriver Logging have the ability to receive logs via the syslog protocol?

I'm using the open source Heroku Logplex router to collect logs. Logplex allows you to set up a drain to send the aggregated logs, but I think it sends it using the syslog format.

I'd like to use Stackdriver Logging, but I can't figure out what syslog URL to send to.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that Stackdriver doesn't accept syslog protocol as detailed here [Does StackDriver support Syslog protocol?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40968943/does-stackdriver-support-syslog-protocol)  . However, syslog is now streamed to stackdriver logging by the Compute Engine logging agent and available in the logging view within GCP.